# OpenCV, Android

Tags: android, opencv

В данный момент изучаю OpenCV по книге "Android Application Programming with OpenCV". Так как вэбки нет, то тестирую на реальном устройстве. Пока работаю над обработкой изображений с помощью фильтров. Вот код одного фильтра:

```
public class StrokeEdgeFilter implements Filter {

Mat mKernel = new MatOfInt(
        0,  0,  1,  0,  0,
        0,  1,  2,  1,  0,
        1,  2,  -16,    2,  1,
        0,  1,  2,  1,  0,
        0,  0,  1,  0,  0);

private final Mat mEdges = new Mat();

@Override
public void apply(Mat src, Mat dst) {

    Imgproc.filter2D(src,mEdges,-1,mKernel);
    Core.bitwise_not(mEdges,mEdges);

    /*вот здесь зависает*/
    Core.multiply(src,mEdges,dst,1.0/255.0);


}
```

}

А вот другого:

```
  public class RecolorRGVFilter implements Filter{
private final ArrayList<Mat> mChannels = new ArrayList<Mat>(4);
@Override
public void apply(Mat src, Mat dst) {
    Core.split(src,mChannels);

    final Mat r = mChannels.get(0);
    final Mat g = mChannels.get(1);
    final Mat b = mChannels.get(2);
    /*вот здесь зависает*/
    Core.min(b,r,b);
    Core.min(b,g,b);

    Core.merge(mChannels, dst);
}
```

}

Есть еще третий, идентичен второму за исключением того, что использован метод Core.max(). Там есть еще фильтры, но они работают, а при выполнении этих трех фильтров зависает в месте, где я указал в коде. Зависает только приложение. Сообщение об ошибке в студии не выводится. Только это в Debug:

```
 Signal: SIGBUS (signal SIGBUS: illegal alignment)
```

На всех доступных устройствах происходит то же самое. Посоветуйте, что в коде не так, или где найти решение.

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно что вы делаете там где у вас зависает (первый фрагмент). 
Зависает кстати потому, что матрицы должны быть одного и того же типа (в данном случае 1-я матрица у вас типа CV_UC8C1, CV_UC8C3 или CV_UC8C4 ( то есть типа byte 1, 3 или 4 канала в зависимости чб, цветная или цветная + альфа картинка на входе), а 2-я матрица - типа CV_32SC1.

Но если я правильно предполагаю, и вам нужно получить просто нормализованную по 1.0 матрицу вещественных чисел - mEdges вам туда передавать ни к чему (уверен что вы сами не понимаете зачем ее туда передаете). 
В этом случае код должен быть:

```
Core.multiply(src,1.0/255.0,dst);
```

и dst - типа CV_64FCx (x - столько каналов у входной матрицы)